# Using textmate for ruby, what how do I move the cursor outside of brackets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, textmate

I'm new to textmate, ruby... programming...

Lets say I'm writing the following:

```
{::Rails:root}
```

Textmate will create both sets of {} when I type the first one. Once I've entered ::Rails:root within the {} how do I get textmate to jump outside of the {} without using the arrow keys? Is there a key stroke or command that I just dont know the name of or is using the arrow keys the correct method?

Thanks for dealing with me seriously new coder question!

Comment: I'd recommend watching the [screencasts](http://macromates.com/screencasts). There's a lot of good info packed into them, and you'll probably stop and back them up repeatedly to see what they're doing.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stay on the same line you simply type '}' to overwrite the autocomplete. If you want to get out of the autocomplete and go directly to the next line its cmd + enter.

If you like to see semicolons at the end of your ruby commands, you also have the option of pressing cmd + shift + enter.

UPDATE: As @Jake stated in the comments, you also have the option of pressing cmd + right arrow to get to the end of the line. You do have to press the arrow but you save keystrokes in cases where there is a nested autocomplete such as

```
("Some text #{variable}")
```

So instead of pressing '}', then '"', then ')' you could simply press cmd + right arrow to get to the end.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just do cmd + enter

Comment: That's what I was thinking but it actually takes you to the next line.

Comment: If you want to stay on the same line you can always just use cmd + right arrow.. that will take you to the end of the current line.  I use that pretty often as well.

Answer (score 0):

Edit -> Select -> Enclosing Brackets might be your friend here, depending on what you're trying to do. Do that then right arrow will take you to the end of the brackets/{}s/etc.

I use a similar approach for one of the macros in my [Motion Commands TextMate Bundle](https://github.com/rwilcox/motion_commands.tmbundle/)